# Quotient group izomorphic with torus

Tags: quotient-group

Let $S^1 = \{ \omega \in \mathbb{C}: \ |\omega| =1 \}$. I need to figure out the relation $\sim$ between two elements of a set $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ such that quotient group $S^1 \times \mathbb{R} / _{\sim}$ will be izomorphic with torus.

Please help.
Thanks
Tommy.

Comment: $S^1\times \mathbb{R}$ describes a cylinder. How can you manipulate a cylinder such that it becomes a torus?

Comment: Infinite cylinder I can cut into equal pieces (finite length cylinders) and roll them such that each of them becomes a torus. Each piece is izomorphic with torus. Quotient group is a set of cosets so each coset is one torus. How to describe it mathematically?

Comment: If I cut infinite cylinder $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ into pieces of lenght say $l$ then:
$(\omega_1 , u) \sim (\omega_2 , t) \leftrightarrow \omega_1 = \omega_2$ and there exist $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|u-t| = k \cdot l$ Is this correct?

Comment: Nicely done, Tommy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already deduced [a scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250637/quotient-group-izomorphic-with-torus#comment6685083_3250637) for equivalence relations that will do the job, but I would suggest a few refinements.

First of all, there's no need for the absolute value bars--we can simply say $u-t=k\cdot l$, instead, and it will make it easier to prove transitivity, without making symmetry particularly difficult to prove.

Second of all, there's no need to leave $l$ general, nor even think of it as a length. Any non-zero real number will do, once we've dropped the absolute value bars, but I'd pick $l=1$ for simplicity. That reduces the condition to $u-t=k.$